# Uploading an image to a database with javafx

Tags: mysql, eclipse, javafx, phpmyadmin

i'm trying to upload an image to mysql database using phpmyadmin and despite the program works and stores the rest of the data the image is not stored correctly.

If I upload an image directly in phpmyadmin the image's size in type Blob it's 26.6 KB but if I try to uploading using javafx the image's size it's about 10 B so I think i'm not uploading correctly.

```
@Override
public void guardarMonstruo(MonstruoDTO monstruo) {
    con= ConexionBDA.getInstance().getCon();
    try {
    if (con != null){
        byte[] blob = imagenToByte(monstruo.getImagen());
        System.out.println(blob.toString());
        statement = con.createStatement();
        statement.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO monstruos (Nombre,Habitat,Estado,ColaCercenable,DragonAnciano,DebilidadFuego,DebilidadAgua,Debilidadrayo,DebilidadHielo,DebilidadDraco,ImagenMonstruo) VALUES ('"+monstruo.getNombre()+"'"+","+"'"+monstruo.getHabitat()+"'"+","+"'"+monstruo.getEstado()+"'"+","+"'"+monstruo.getColaCercenable()+"'"+","+"'"+monstruo.getDragonAnciano()+"'"+","+"'"+monstruo.getDebilidadFuego()+"'"+","+"'"+monstruo.getDebilidadAgua()+"'"+","+"'"+monstruo.getDebilidadRayo()+"'"+","+"'"+monstruo.getDebilidadHielo()+"'"+","+"'"+monstruo.getDebilidadDraco()+"'"+","+"'"+blob+"');");
        con.close();
        statement.close();


    }
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

And the method imagenToByte() is used to pass the image to byte is this:

```
private byte[] imagenToByte(Image imagen) {
    BufferedImage bufferimage = SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(imagen, null);
      ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
      try {
        ImageIO.write(bufferimage, "jpg", output );
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
      byte [] data = output.toByteArray();
      return data;
}
```

I don't know what i'm doing wrong, could you please help me?

Comment: Its not that unrelated. Prepared statements will save you from SQL injection and allow you to insert blob data into tables. Are you sure your code isn't throwing an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You insert the result of the `toString` method to the query string which won't result in the desired outcome. Use `PreparedStatement` and set a `Blob` parameter instead:

```
try (PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO monstruos (Nombre,Habitat,Estado,ColaCercenable,DragonAnciano,DebilidadFuego,DebilidadAgua,Debilidadrayo,DebilidadHielo,DebilidadDraco,ImagenMonstruo) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)")) {
    ps.setString(1, monstruo.getNombre());
    ps.setString(2, monstruo.getHabitat());
    ps.setString(3, monstruo.getEstado());
    ps.setString(4, monstruo.getColaCercenable());
    ps.setString(5, monstruo.getDragonAnciano());
    ps.setString(6, monstruo.getDebilidadFuego());
    ps.setString(7, monstruo.getDebilidadAgua());
    ps.setString(8, monstruo.getDebilidadRayo());
    ps.setString(9, monstruo.getDebilidadHielo());
    ps.setString(10, monstruo.getDebilidadDraco());

    // upload the data, not the toString result of the array
    ps.setBlob(11, new SerialBlob(blob));

    ps.executeUpdate();
}
```

Comment: It works perfectly, you are a genius, thank you so much!!